# Disable prompt to overwrite config files during upgrade

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg, configuration

I'm trying to configure an Ubuntu (20.04) desktop instance so that the Ubuntu Software Updater GUI does not prompt whether to update a config file if it has local changes (e.g. sshd_config)
[image]

For some background, we manage these Ubuntu Desktops for our organisation with Puppet, and apply a custom sshd_config file (among other things).

I've tried the following `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10dpkg_options file` which seems to prevent overwriting the config files, but I'm still prompted when performing updates in the GUI. As far as I can tell, it doesn't matter what I select at the prompt because it's ignored in favour of our Dpkg::Options.

However, I'd still like to prevent the prompt, since I'd like to avoid confusing our users and reduce the number of tickets we receive.

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10dpkg_options
Dpkg::Options {
  "--force-confdef";
  "--force-confold";
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this and have a fix?